# Jenkins DSL - How to create directory?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-dsl

```
folder('myfoler') {}
```

Above DSL Syntax from https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/folder  allowing me to create a folder `myfoler`. I need to create a directory.

Tried this:

```
folder('myfoler/mysubfoler') {}
```

This gives me error `ERROR: Could not create item, unknown parent path in "myfoler/mysubfoler"`

How do I create a full directory in single step?

Comment: Please explain the reason for negative vote. Thee question seems very straightforward. I have explained with example and what I tried too

Answer (score -1):

you need to create parent folder and then nested

```
folder('myfoler') {}
folder('myfoler/mysubfoler') {}
```

you can use function to generate this

```
void createAllDirectories(String path) {
    String[] directories = path.split('/')
    String currentPath = ""

    directories.each { directory ->
        currentPath += directory + '/'
        folder(currentPath) {}
    }
}

// Example usage:
String path = "my/super/long/sweet/path"
createAllDirectories(path)
```

Comment: yeah. I know that. But the ask was on how to create this entire directory on a single step. Imagine the directory path comes from a variable..  For example : 'ab/cd/ef/gh' . Is the only way is to separately create each path ?  'ab', 'ab/cd', 'ab/cd/ef', 'ab/cd/ef/gh' ? This sounds weird. There should be some easy way!

Comment: https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/c8a3dc07ef50c05645e8ad5cb41a237edb0e2662/job-dsl-plugin/src/main/java/javaposse/jobdsl/plugin/JenkinsJobManagement.java#L515-L536

see this 

its expected by plugin code 
it can not create item without parent item